# SQL Query Help for Access 2013

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I have a table

```
ID    | Rev Date   | Rev Status | Details 
1     | 12/05/2013 | ACTIVE     | A
2     | 03/05/2015 | REVIEW     | B
3     | 04/05/2013 | ACTIVE     | C
4     | 05/05/2015 | REVIEW     | A
5     | 06/08/2015 | ACTIVE     | C
6     | 05/08/2014 | ACTIVE     | B
```

I would like to get the all Records where both an entry with Status ACTIVE and REVIEW exist.

```
1     | 12/05/2013  |ACTIVE     | A
5     | 05/05/2015  |REVIEW     | A

6     | 05/08/2014  |ACTIVE     | B
2     | 03/05/2015  |REVIEW     | B
```

Can someone please assist with this.

Comment: this is really simple `Select * FROM table_name WHERE \`Rev Status\` IN ('ACTIVE', REVIEW)`

Comment: @LuthandoLoot The problem isn't to get the rows with either ACTIVE or REVIEW, it's to get the ones with _both_ which is a bit more trickier... note that the desired output only has four rows, and not six, which your sample query would return.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so to get the Detail groups that have both ACTIVE and REVIEW status you need to use a subquery (or derived table) that filters out the Detail groups with both statuses and then use that as input to get the rest of the details.

One way to do it:

```
select * from t 
where details in (
  select Details 
  from t 
  group by Details
  having sum(iif([rev status] = 'ACTIVE', 1, 0)) > 0
     and sum(iif([rev status] = 'REVIEW', 1, 0)) > 0
) ;
```

Given your sample data this would return the rows for Details A and B as they have both statuses but exclude Details C as it only has Active.